# backgrounded job keeps stopping

Tags: command-line, background-process, jobs

I am seeing some strange behavior on my RHEL6 bash prompt.  I often like to execute command lines that look like ...

```
$ ./myscript > junk 2>&1
```

... then hit <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> and then execute ...

```
$ bg
$ tail -f junk
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
```

But today for some reason I am see that my job stays "stopped" and is not "running".

```
$ uname -a
Linux myhost 2.6.18-371.11.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 04:51:39 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
$ ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1
$ bg
[1]+ ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1 &
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1
```

The script I am running is nothing exotic ...

```
#!/bin/sh

count=`wc -l hostlist`
total=1
for i in `grep -v "^#" hostlist`
do
    echo "Doing $total or $count $i"
    sudo scp -q access.sh $i:/tmp
    sudo ssh -q $i /tmp/access.sh
    sleep 1
    total=`expr $total + 1`
done
```

Comment: See if giving  `ssh` a `-n` option helps. Without that, it will try to read from stdin, and if that happens in a background job, it usually gets stopped  (it gets a SIGTTIN signal).

Comment: `sudo` has a time limit.  Wonder if that could be an issue.  Did you run the script using sudo?

Comment: Thanks Mark Plotnick! That did the trick. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$ bg
[1]+ ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1 &
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1
```

Running `jobs -l` will show more detail about your background jobs. In the case of your shell script, it will display something like the following, which reveals the reason why the job stopped:

```
[1]+  4274 Stopped (tty input)     ./myscript.sh > output-07-JUL-16.txt 2>&1
```

Something in your script is trying to read from the terminal. When a background job tries to read from its controlling terminal, it gets a `SIGTTIN` signal and stops. (Only the foreground job can read from the controlling terminal.)

The cause: in your script, you have

```
sudo ssh -q $i /tmp/access.sh
```

ssh by default will try to read from its stdin. You can give ssh the `-n` option to tell it not to read from stdin.

```
sudo ssh -n -q $i /tmp/access.sh
```

Comment: I upvoted this very informative answer as I learned that `jobs -l` does more than simply “lists process IDs in addition to the normal information”. I had similar issues running X11 applications on a remote host in the background so using the `-n` option (or the recommded`-f` option which implies `-n`) solved those issues.

Comment: In my case the program was Synopsys DVE started in gui mode. Using `nohup`, e.g. `nohup simv -gui` instead of `simv -gui` fixed my `Stopped (tty input)` problem.